# GAS: How to create a globally accessible Array variable across multiple functions

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

So, I have been asked to rephrase my question post. I actually thought it would make sense if I shared a picture of what I need to accomplish. My apologies for not knowing the format. But anywho ...

**Required**:
I have a spreadsheet file and a user enters a value in a specific cell (see picture below). I want that value be stored along with the current date in a two dimensional array.

[image: Screen Shot]

**What my code does:** This code is 
(1) Using a PropertiesService to store a value globally
(2) Accepting user input in H3 cell and is updating J3 cell with a date of format mm/dd and appending the user input. For e.g., if user inputs 4 in H3 and current date is 8/29/2019, then J3 will display "8/29::4"
(3) This code also adds a comment with the above value in H3

**Error/Issue**
(1) When I try to declare an array in the onEdit function and attempt to write something into it, it is spitting this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at onEdit(Code:21:29)**

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
scriptProperties.setProperty('i', 0);


function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "H3") 
  {  
    var difference = isNaN(e.value) ? 0 : Number(e.value);  
    var date = (new Date()); 
    var monthValue = date.getMonth();    
    var dateValue = date.getDate();
    var wholeValues = [];

    monthValue = monthValue+1;
    dateValue = dateValue-1;
    var logTimestamp = monthValue+"/"+dateValue;
    e.range.getSheet().getRange("J3").setValue(logTimestamp+"::"+difference+";"); 
    e.range.setNote(logTimestamp+"::"+difference+";");

    var arrayIndex = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty('i')); 
    wholeValues[arrayIndex].push("Sample Data");
    arrayIndex = arrayIndex + 1;
    Logger.log("wholeValues size is " +wholeValues.length);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post--your post should use images to help illustrate text, not to remove the question from your post, and you should clearly state what the problem you are experiencing is. Providing an example spreadsheet may also help.

Comment: As to your issue, the way I would do it is to store your other values on an extra sheet (e.g., cells in the top row, dates on the A column, values on each date in each cell's associated column on each associated date). It is then fairly trivial to get/write each value in each cell for the correct date, and retrieve the values later. see also the `onEdit(e)` trigger

Comment: What is your problem with the current code? See [mre]. You should provide a clear problem statement/error if any.

Comment: @TheMaster: I have rephrased my question. I hope it is in line with the question format. Could you please help

Comment: @sinaraheneba: Storing values in different places of the spreadsheet is not efficient as per my requirements. I need an array to accomplish this and having an array would let me search the items at a later time.

Comment: Wouldn't a object be easier? {date:value} ?

Comment: @Jrules80 I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'efficient', other than taking a longer time. Something to consider: You can combine storing keys in the cache/property service (as Tanaike suggests) with storing them in the sheet to get the benefits of both; especially in keeping it (backed up) in a sheet, others will easily be able to use the data, you can easily access it through sheet formulas, and the information can be easily backed up by simply making a copy of the sheet.

Comment: Come to think of it, Sinaraheneba, I would look into the option of storing values in a hidden worksheet like you suggested. I have not explored it but this seems to be a viable option as long as I am able to hide the sheet. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues:

- `wholeValues` array is local and won't persist across sessions/function calls/script runs.
- `wholeValues` is a empty array all the time.
- `i` will always be `"0"` as you're setting it to 0 in global scope each time a function is called.
- `wholeValues[0]`(=[][0]) is `undefined` as  there is no element with index 0. `undefined` doesn't have `.push` function. Therefore, `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

#### Solution:

Different approaches can be made:

1. Create a object `dateObj` with value `{date1:value1,date2:value2,...}` and store it in properties as a string.
2. Set the datestring itself as a key to properties. Here each property is object containing `{date:value}`
3. You can save the array in a log sheet.

#### Snippet:

```
/*var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
scriptProperties.setProperty('i', 0);*/ //Removed from global scope


function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "H3") 
  {  
   /* Rest of your code*/
    e.range.setNote(logTimestamp+"::"+difference+";");

    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var dateObjStr = scriptProperties.getProperty('dateObj'); 
    var dateObj = dateObjStr ? JSON.parse(dateObjStr) : {};
    var dateStr = Utilities.formatDate(date, e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd");
    dateObj[dateStr] = difference;//{"2019-08-28": 6}
    scriptProperties.setProperty('dateObj', JSON.stringify(dateObj));
  }
}
```

#### Snippet#2:

```
    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var dateStr = Utilities.formatDate(date, e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd");
    scriptProperties.setProperty(dateStr, difference);
    var dateVal = scriptProperties.getProperty(dateStr) || 0; //Retrieval
```

#### Snippet#3:

```
    var dateStr = Utilities.formatDate(date, e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd");
    e.source.getSheetByName('LogSheet').appendRow([dateStr, difference]);
```

#### References:

- [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

  > Properties value size     9kB / val
  > Properties total storage  500kB / property store
  > Properties read/write     50,000 - 500,000/ day
- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)
- [Utilities#formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. I'll check and report soon.

Comment: A few questions: 1. Are Snipper #2 and #3 part of the onEdit function? 2. How long does the variable dateStr persist? 3. Why can't I use an Array? I'd really appreciate if you'd give me an example of how to achieve this with a persistable array.

Comment: @Jrules 1. Yes(alternative ways to snippet#1) 2. It doesn't. It dies immediately after function ends.  Whatever is put in Properties persist. 3.  Given your requirement, objects are the best choice.

Comment: If I could persist objects indefinitely, can I use them like arrays? The reason why I ask is, as part of my requirement, I need to be able to go back and update the hours (difference variable) for a given timestamp. How do I do this with an object?

Comment: So, this is what I did:
 scriptProperties.setProperty(dateStr, difference);
    var data = scriptProperties.getProperties();
//    var dateVal = scriptProperties.getProperty(value) || 0; //Retrieval
    for (var key in data) {
      Logger.log('Key: %s, Value: %s', key, data[key]);
    }
It is now able to retrieve "Date" and "User Input". But, the next time, user enters a value, it is being overwritten. I do not want that. I want to persist old "Date" and "User Input" values  :(

Comment: @Jrules *But, the next time, user enters a value, it is being overwritten.* Isn't that what you want? It's only overwritten for the current date. You don't have to loop through find the date, erase 6 and make it 10(see your picture last para). When a new day comes, new date entry,new value is stored indefinitely subject to quota. If you want to find the last updated value for a given date, you can get it from script properties using that dateStr as a key(You can also see it in File> project settings> properties).

Comment: @Jrules *I have not explored it but this seems to be a viable option as long as I am able to hide the sheet.* Snippet#3 might help.